# Haskell FFI: Wrapping a C struct containing a separately allocated string (char*)

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, storable, haskell-ffi

Suppose you have a C-struct

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t num;
  char*    str;
} MyStruct;
```

and a function `f` that does some operation on it,

```
void f(MyStruct* p);
```

The C API demands that the `char*` be allocated a sufficient buffer before calling `f`:

```
char buf[64];   //the C API docs say 64
MyStruct s = {1, buf};
f(s);  // would go badly if MyStruct.str isn't alloc'ed
```

(Note that the `num` field has no purpose in this constructed example. It just prevents the trivial solution using `CString` and `CStringLen`.)

**The question is how to write a Haskell FFI for this kind of C API.**

What I've come up with is this: Start with

```
data MyStruct = MyStruct {
    num :: Word32,
    str :: String
} deriving Show
```

and write a Storable instance. My idea is to allocate 64 bytes at the end which will serve as buffer for the string:

```
instance Storable MyStruct where
    sizeOf _ = 8{-alignment!-} + sizeOf (nullPtr :: CString) + 64{-buffer-}
    alignment _ = 8
```

`poke` has to change the pointer in str to point to the allocated buffer, and then the Haskell string has to be copied into it. I do this with `withCStringLen`:

```
poke p x = do
    pokeByteOff p 0 (num x)
    poke strPtr bufPtr
    withCStringLen (str x) $ \(p',l) -> copyBytes bufPtr p' (l+1) -- not sure about the +1
    where strPtr = castPtr $ plusPtr p 8 :: Ptr CString
          bufPtr = castPtr $ plusPtr p 16 :: CString
```

Finally here's `peek`, which is straightforward:

```
peek p = MyStruct 
     <$> peek (castPtr p)
     <*> peekCAString (castPtr $ plusPtr p 16)
```

All this works, but I find it rather ugly. **Is this the way to do it, or is there a better way?**

If anyone wants to play with it, the little toy problem is on [github](https://github.com/mcmayer/soq-struct-string).

**Update**

As pointed out by `chi` the following caveat is in order: Using hard-coded alignments and offsets is bad practice. They are fragile and platform/compiler dependent. Instead, tools like [c2hsc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hsc), [c2hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs)  or [bindings-dsl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-DSL), or [greencard](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/greencard), etc., should be used.

Comment: I would keep your approach, trying to remove all the magic numbers like 8 and 16, replacing them with some code which actually computes the size of a C int, and the proper offset. Maybe tools like `c2hs` can help in computing these numbers, but I don't remember. A potential alternative could be to use foreign pointers for the allocation of the buffer, and let the buffer be freed on GC. I am not that familiar with FFI to guarantee this is viable.

Answer (score 0):

While your solution seems quite nice for me (you are hiding that memory fiddling inside `Storable` instance, so that user shouldn't bother finding a memory buffer himself), you can mimic C solution too with [`allocaBytes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html).

Comment: One risk I see is that a user does an `alloca` and then passes the pointer to the `f` function which will then probably throw a segfault.

Comment: Why would it? The memory will be freed once `f` finishes. It can happen if user will save this pointer using some `IORef` and then try to use it later, but the documentation warns about it.

Comment: `alloca` just allocates sufficient memory but doesn't do the pointer-bending which makes `str` point to the proper buffer. It'd need some initializer function after the `alloca` before handing down the `Ptr`.